# What qualifies an x-ray line as "useful for quantification" in a material's x-ray analysis?

Tags: electrons, radiation, data-analysis, x-rays, microscopy

**Original question:**

Knowing the energy values for the different X-ray lines for Mo and for S in the analysis of bulk MoS$_2$
($K_{\alpha 1}$, $K_{\alpha 2}$$K_{\beta1}$, $L_{\alpha 1}$, $L_{\beta1}$, etc.)and knowing the electron's accelerating voltage (let's say X keV),  **how do I know which X-ray lines can be used for quantification?**

**I am not presenting any real values as I would simply like to know what determines an X-ray line viable to be used for quantification.**

Is it in any way related to the accelerating voltage or to the energy resolution of an EDX detector?

I understand that these rays are obtained via the decay of excited electrons to a lower energy level and I have also been presented with results that demonstrate the different wt% values of some of these rays in different materials, but I do not understand how this quantification process occurs or, as stated above, what qualifies certain rays to be used in it.

---

**Edit:**

I have re-written the question exactly as it was presented to me in order to give a better understanding of the problem which I am afraid of having poorly explained due to my lack of understanding:

*Consider X-ray analysis of bulk MoS$_2$.  In KeV, Mo has X-ray lines:*

K$_{\alpha 1}$ - 17.48;
                 K$_{\alpha 2}$ - 17.37;                     
K$_{\beta 1}$ - 19.61;

L$_{\alpha 1}$ - 2.293;                  L$_{\alpha 2}$ - 2.290;                  L$_{\beta 1}$ - 2.395;              L$_{\beta 2}$ - 2.518;              L$_{\gamma 1}$ - 2.623,

*while S has:*

K$_{\alpha 1}$ - 2.308;                 K$_{\alpha 2}$ - 2.307;                   K$_{\beta1}$ - 2.464.

*In practice the energy resolution of an EDX detector is > 50 eV so we only need to consider K-alpha, K-beta, etc. At an accelerating voltage of 20 kV, which X-ray lines could be used for quantification?*

*Select one or more:*

a. All peaks apart from Mo K-beta

b. Any peaks that do not overlap within the resolution of the spectrometer

c. Any of Mo K and S K

d. Mo K-beta and S K-alpha

e. Any of Mo L and S K

f. Mo K-alpha and S K-alpha

I don't intend to have an exact answer to the problem but instead, I would like to know **what makes an X-ray line useful for quantification?**

Answer (score 0):

Quantification can be quite tricky. There may be other elements in the sample under study with an absorption threshold between the $K_\alpha$ and $K_\beta$ of the element that you want to quantify.

The $L_\alpha$ peak of the iron-row transition metals may be self-absorbed, depending also on oxidation states.

So to do this really accurately, one needs to compare with similar standards. It is a bit of an art.

Comment: In the example I have been given I have been told that the sample is a MoS$_2$ and I have been given real energy values for the different $K_\alpha$, $K_\beta$ and $L_\alpha$, etc, lines, as well as values for the accelerating voltage and for the energy resolution of an EDX detector.

No explanation has been given to me, and I  have no sources of information.
Would the energy values of those rays make some of them viable to use for quantification? What determines this viability?

I understand that it is quite tricky but I have no other source of information. Thank you

Comment: @user7077252 Who needs quantification when the composition is known? So this is a silly school exercise. Well, the electron energy would need to be clearly higher than 20 keV to get any Mo K emission. The sulphur L lines are at 150 eV or so, too low and too weak to be useful for anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to quite understand the answer, but I have reworded the question in hopes it is clearer.